# Dynamic webpage for each row in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a working database that will list all of the records just fine. However, I need for each row to have it's own link to a small webpage that will display the fields. I assume that it should use the primary key which is simply labeled as id.

When the records are listed I need the first and last name to have a generated hyperlink that when clicked on would take the browser to a webpage that echos the fields for that row.

The database uses the fields:

- id
- firstname
- lastname
- department
- interests
- email

I'm trying to use `$_GET` in a form that can pull the data - but still not working and I'm not sure how to generate the hyperlink during the `SELECT * from test_table` query in the code.

This is the output for the list:

Using query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY `test_table`.`name` ASC ";

echo "<table width='100%'>"; // bgcolor = $repeating_panel_bgcolor
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='300' valign='top'>";
echo $row['name'];
echo ", Dr.&nbsp;";
echo $row['firstname'];
echo "<br>";echo $row['department'];
echo "<br>";echo $row['email'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td valign='top'>";
echo $row['interests'];
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _“I'm trying to use $_GET in a form that can pull the data”_ – I don’t see any form, and neither any links in the code you’ve shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this

```
$id   = $row['user_id'];
$name = $row['first_name'];
echo "<td><a href='details.php?id=$id&name=$name'>$name</a></td>";
```

This makes just that cell clickable.  You can not apply it to the row.

Comment: _“This makes just that cell clickable. You can apply it to the row if you wish”_ – no, you can not, not with an `a` element, because that can not be a child of `tr`.

Comment: @CBroe, are you saying that the **<a>** tag can not be applied to **<tr>**.  You may well be right, although I can not find any such statement at w3schools.  I normally use **<ul>/<li>** for this function.  Editing my answer

Comment: w3schools is not a good reference (http://www.w3fools.com/). Instead, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element, “Content model”

Comment: Still have issues so I have tried to break it down. I used to suggestion above for the link to a page named details.php -- echo "<td><a href='details.php?$id'>$name</a></td>"; All I need in for the details.php to pull up the fields for that record. So do I need to use     $id = $_GET["id"]; $name = $_GET["name"];   Then echo '[$name]';  this is not working. Made sure that I am connected to the database

Comment: With above you are only passing the id, the name is getting displayed as its after the angle bracket.  If you need both, you need to pass both to details.php.  Editing my answer above.